# Collapse mobile header when somewhere else on the page is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently working with a really basic header (I eventually want it to animate when opening and collapsing and have the hamburger menu animate to/from the close icon). The header is responsive and the user can collapse it when tapping the close icon. How can I make it collapse whenever somewhere other than the header is tapped:

Here's what I'm working with so far.

```css
body,
html {
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 0vw;
  margin: 0vw;
}

.header {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  right: 0%;
  height: 10vh;
  z-index: 1;
  border-bottom: solid;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.headerfill {
  height: 10vh;
  border: none;
}

.header-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.logo-container {
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
  padding-left: 1vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: left;
}

.navigation-container {
  width: 60%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  //justify-content: space-evenly; 
  margin: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.space-evenly {
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .logo-container {
    float: left;
    width: 80%;
    padding-left: 1vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: left;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .navigation-container {
    width: 20%;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    //justify-content: space-evenly; 
    margin: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .space-evenly {
    justify-content: space-evenly;
  }
}

.logo {
  height: 8vh;
  max-width: 40%;
  padding-top: 1.5vh;
  padding-bottom: 0.5vh;
  padding-left: 4vh;
  display: block;
  object-fit: contain;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .logo {
    height: 8vh;
    max-width: 80%;
    padding-top: 1.5vh;
    padding-bottom: 0.5vh;
    padding-left: 2vh;
    display: block;
    object-fit: contain;
  }
}

img {
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
}

.nav {
  font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
  font-size: 2vw;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  color: #000000;
  padding-left: auto;
  padding-right: auto;
  line-height: 1em;
  object-fit: contain;
  text-decoration: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .nav {
    font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
    font-size: 8vw;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 2vh;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    color: #000000;
    padding-left: 2vh;
    padding-right: 2vh;
    line-height: 1em;
    object-fit: contain;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}

.nav:hover {
  color: #096e67;
}

a:link {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
  font-size: 4vw;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  color: #000000;
  padding-left: 4vh;
  padding-right: 2vh;
  padding-bottom: 0.5vh;
  line-height: 1em;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  h1 {
    font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
    font-size: 8vw;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    color: #000000;
    padding-left: 2vh;
    padding-right: 2vh;
    padding-bottom: 0.5vh;
    line-height: 1em;
  }
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: right;
}

nav a {
  display: block;
}

i {
  display: none !important;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: none;
  }
  nav.active {
    display: block;
    background-color: aqua;
    border-top: solid;
    border-bottom: green solid 0.2vh;
    padding: 1vh;
    padding-bottom: 2vh;
  }
  i {
    display: block!important;
    margin: 5px;
  }
}

.fa {
  font-size: 6vh;
  padding-top: 2vh;
  padding-bottom: 2vh;
  padding: 0vh;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en-GB">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Website Header</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./stylesheet.css">
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <div class="header">
      <div class="header-container">
        <div class="logo-container">
          <img class="logo" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt="Logo">
        </div>
        <div class="navigation-container space-evenly">
          <nav>
            <a href="#">
              <p class="nav">Page1</p>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
              <p class="nav">Page2</p>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
              <p class="nav">Page3</p>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
              <p class="nav">Page4</p>
            </a>
          </nav>



          <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <script>
    menu = document.querySelector('nav');
    document.querySelector('i')
      .addEventListener('click', e => {
        menu.classList.toggle('active')
        document.querySelector('header i').classList.toggle('fa-bars')
        document.querySelector('header i').classList.toggle('fa-times')
      })
  </script>

  <div class="header-fill">
  </div>
```

There's quite a lot. I'd just like it so if the user decides to tap somewhere else they don't have to click the close button in case they decide to stick with that page.

Bonus if someone can figure out how to add bootstrap for expansion and collapse of the header (in mobile view) and to animate the close/hamburger menu.

Quite stuck,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: your already doing great :) you can use java script and set an event handler to the rest of the page apart from your navigation part eg: `onmousedown` then check if the navigation is open ? if open close it. if you still need a more explained answer let me know.

Comment: Yeah, you lost me after `onmousedown`, not sure how to make it collapse. Once I've figured this out I need to be able yo animate it :/  Thanks in advance, @BobbyAxe

Comment: if you can see https://youtu.be/0ik6X4DJKCc 4 video tutorial to get you up to speed on java script

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).click(function() {
  $("nav").removeClass("active")
})

$("nav").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation()
  return false
})

$(".fa.fa-bars").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation()
  $("nav").toggleClass("active")
})
```

Comment: That doesn't work. I've tested it on an actual mobile device too.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve you problem let me know the outcome

```
let button =document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', buttonClick);
function buttonClick(e)
{
    //to view current target on console
    console.log(e.target);

    //checks if you've clicked out side the nav
    if(!e.target.classList.contains('navigation-container'))
    {
        //checks if nav is open
        if(document.querySelector('nav').classList.contains('active'))
        {
            console.log('now closing nav');

            //from your code this should close the nav but adjust to close the nav if this dose not work
            menu.classList.toggle('active')
            document.querySelector('header i').classList.toggle('fa-bars')
            document.querySelector('header i').classList.toggle('fa-times')
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: **Note:** That the `querySelector('body')` is selecting your body tags therefore the `<body></body>` should be properly closed.

Comment: @phphelpplease did you try out the fix? what was the outcome?

Comment: Apologies, I've been distracted with other developments. I've tried it but now the buttons toggle but the drop-down isn't shown at all.