# Adding bootstrap to an existing header for collapse & using bootstrap animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

This is a new question and I mentioned it in my previous one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52022235/collapse-mobile-header-when-somewhere-else-on-the-page-is-clicked?noredirect=1#comment91013997_52022235) just to save posting the code again.

I don't want to start over so I was wondering how I'd go about making the navbar collapse but in an animated way, the code I have works but the navbar still doesn't collapse when clicked off. Would this also be done with bootstrap?

Completely new to bootstrap animations and I can't find any libraries with good instructions or examples. Any links would be appreciated, as well as a fix to my header issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Bounce ](https://github.com/tictail/bounce.js), Go to Readme they have given some instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Vist this [link](https://www.sitepoint.com/our-top-9-animation-libraries/) they have listed 9 libraries, when you click on the link of library it will redirect you to github and there in ReadMe they have given explanation related to the library.

Comment: Thank you, that's useful for animating other elements, what about animating the header & its icon?